# How to fix connection issue with mariadb in amazon RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mariadb, rds

I have created an AMAZON RDS mariadb database under free tier.

I used a random generated password first but it is not connecting.

So, I click modify and updated the database with new password.

but still, I am getting error as below.

```
(conn=36) Access denied for user 'root'@'175.101.107.213' (using password: YES)
Current charset is windows-1252. If password has been set using other charset, consider using option 'passwordCharacterEncoding'
```

[image]

But I updated the password multiple times but same issue everytime.

Please suggest how to fix that.
I checked the passwordCharacterEncoding option in the dbeaver, it is having an empty value.

Comment: Are you using the same password you defined in the AWS console? Try a password without punctuation or special characters. Try MySql to see if it works any differently. It will most likely be user error wrong as thousands of those databases will be created each day, but exactly what... not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Are you connecting from an external host?

By default mariadb connection policies are restrictive and they only allow for local connections, unless you specify otherwise. Check your configuration file and look for the following line:

```
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
```

If you want to listen to external connections you should comment that line out and restart the service.

Also note is not a good idea to connect to your database as root, and in some environments (I don't know specifically for Amazon RDS) root login is also disabled for network connections.

Edit: This can be done from Amazon RDS console by setting the **Publicly Accessible** property of your instance to **Yes**:

[My DB instance is in a public subnet, and I can't connect to it over the internet from my local computer](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-connectivity-instance-subnet-vpc/)

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet.
In addition to simplifying the password (for testing), make sure the username matches what was set for the "Master username" when the RDS instance is created.

For MariaDB on RDS the default is "admin".